# How do you create a Python program on which you can drag files on to open it?

Tags: python-3.x, file

I am aware that there are multiple Python programs where the user can drag a file *onto* said Python program's icon, and the program does something with the file picked by the user. How is this done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The path to the file will be stored in the sys.argv[1] variable. There you can use it for enything you want.
Example:

```
import sys
    with open (sys.argv[1]) as f:
        print(f.read())

input()
```

Comment: Thanks! This helps a lot!